# Read All the available records in emv at once

Tags: nfc, smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard, emv

what simple apdu command can I use to read all the data from available record and sfi

```
0x00,0xB2,0x01,0x0C,0x00
```

currently am using the above to read data from from sfi 1 record 1

**It works** and I get data and **90 00**

when I try other sfi and record combination like

```
0x00,0xB2,0x01,0x10,0x00
```

I get a record not found sw

So what apdu command can I use to read data from all possible/available records

Answer (score 1):

You should not use any hard coded values. Get the AFL from GET PO, and then use it to form your READ RECORD APDUs. If AFL does not exist, you do not need to go for READ RECORDs.